# How make the program create number of soldiers specified by player?

Tags: java, arrays, object, while-loop, do-while

How make the program create number of  soldiers specified by player?Next to is translate

System.out.println("Jak se budou jmenovat? ");//Soldiers name
        String nazevJednotky;//name

```
    nazevJednotky  = sc.nextLine();

    Vojak[] armada = new Vojak[4];//Soldiers

    String pokracovat = "ano";//String continue = "yes";
    do {
        while(pokracovat.equals("ano")) {

    Vojak pesak = new Pesak(nazevJednotky,0,0,0,mec,stribrne,2);//Pleb      
    Vojak lucistnik = new Strelec(nazevJednotky,0,0,0,luk,kuze,0,0,5);//Archer
    Vojak jizda = new Jizda(nazevJednotky,0,0,0,kopi,stribrne,10);//Cavalry
    Vojak TezkaJednotka = new Tezkajednotka(nazevJednotky,0,0,30,mec,zlate,20);//Special unit
    Vojak[] armadaHrace1 = new Vojak[] {pesak,lucistnik,jizda,TezkaJednotka};
```

///Report for player

```
    for(int i = 0;i < armadaHrace1.length;i++) {

        System.out.println(armadaHrace1[i]);
                           //First PLayer's army
    }


     System.out.println("Jaké si vybereš?");//What is your choice?
        System.out.println("Pešák-0(2)"); //Pleb(how much is the soldir expensive)
        System.out.println("Lučištník-1 (5)");//Archer
        System.out.println("Jezdectvo-2 (10)");//Cavalry
       System.out.println("Težká jednotka-3 (20)");//Special unit

       int vyberVojaky =  Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());//choose soldiers
       Vojak vojaci = null;//soldiers
        System.out.println("A kolik jich chceš?");//How many soldiers do you want?
        int pocetVojaku = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            //numb

       vojaci = armadaHrace1[vyberVojaky]; //soldiers

                                           //getPrize()
       penize -= armadaHrace1[vyberVojaky].getCena();
       System.out.println("Vybral sis" + armadaHrace1[vyberVojaky]);
    System.out.println("Zůstalo ti:" + penize + " " +"peněz");//residue
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Chcete dále vybírat? [ano/ne]");//Do you want to continue?
    pokracovat = sc.nextLine();
    //continue
        }


    }while(penize != 0 );
    //while(money != 0);
```

Comment: You need to tell us what you've tried and what isn't working.
However the answer is probably going to be: Use a `List` instead of an array. Google for "java List tutorial" or similar and see what you can learn from that.

Comment: I got it. System.out.println("How many soldiers do you want?");
   int numb = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
   for(int i=0;i < numb;i++) {
             System.out.println(FirstPlayerarmy[chooseSoldiers]);   
   }

Comment: Well done @PetrBarabáš. Post your answer now and accepted !

Answer (score 0):

```java
//creating variable choooseSoldiers 
int vyberVojaky;
            int pocetVojaku; // numberofSoldiers
            int celkovyPocet = 50;//how many soldiers user can recruit
            boolean Kontrola = true;// boolean control= true;,if user will recruit more than 50 soldiers, control will be false and program will end
            
         do {
                
        
        
        do {
              //which soldiers user can recruit
            Texty nabidkaVojaku = new Texty();
            nabidkaVojaku.nabidkaVojaku();
               vyberVojaky =  Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
              //how many soldiers do you want?
                System.out.println("A kolik jich chceš?");
                 pocetVojaku = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
             for(int i=0;i < pocetVojaku;i++) {
                 System.out.println(armadaHrace1[vyberVojaky]); 
                 
             }

              //variable for condition
               celkovyPocet = celkovyPocet - pocetVojaku;
               vojaci = armadaHrace1[vyberVojaky];//picking soldiers
               penize -= armadaHrace1[vyberVojaky].getCena();//deduction of money for recruitment
               System.out.println("Vybral sis" + armadaHrace1[vyberVojaky]);
                   //You've picked soldier:
            System.out.println("Zůstalo ti:" + penize + " " +"peněz");
            //How many money user still have
                
            
        
         }while(celkovyPocet !=  0);
           if(celkovyPocet >  50 ) {
               System.out.println("Naverboval jsi více jak 50 vojáků");
                 Kontrola = false;
           }
           if(celkovyPocet <= 50) {
            Kontrola = true;
           }
    }while(Kontrola == false);
```

Comment: Please explain how this code answers the question, especially since most of it is not in English.